# how to add full x11 support for imx6 board in yocto krogoth

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I have krogoth yocto source when i compile `bitbake core-image-sato` its showing nearly 4560 packages are compiling but after successfull compilation the rootfs size is 30 mb only.

```
Note: when I boot with this 30 mb size rootfs board is booting but lcd xwindow display not coming.
```

why all packages are not added to core-image-sato

my `core-image-sato.bb`

> DESCRIPTION = "core-image-sato basic image "
>
> IMAGE_FEATURES += "splash package-management x11-base x11-sato
>   ssh-server-dropbear hwcodecs"
>
> LICENSE = "MIT"
>
> inherit core-image
>
> IMAGE_INSTALL += "packagegroup-core-x11-sato-games"

Did i missing anything else? Below is my
 `distro yogurt.conf`

> require conf/distro/poky.conf require common.inc
>
> DISTRO = "yogurt" DISTRO_NAME = "Yogurt (Phytec Example
>   Distribution)"  DISTRO_FEATURES += "systemd x11"
>   DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "argp irda pcmcia zeroconf ptest multiarch
>   wayland"
>
> VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_dev_manager = "udev" VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager =
>   "systemd" DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED += "sysvinit"
>   VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_login_manager = "busybox" VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_syslog = ""
>   VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = ""
>   some default locales
>   IMAGE_LINGUAS ?= "de-de fr-fr en-us"

2. Also when I see `tmp/work/cortexa8-...../` all packages are compiled but no `image dir` is creating for all packages. but i believe those are compiled.
    Why those all packages are not created image dir. is there any reason . Please help me to solve this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use DISTRO_FEATURES += because the default is a ?= assignment.  Use DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " x11 systemd"

Same for IMAGE_INSTALL.  The default is a += assignment, so what you're doing is creating an image that just contains the sato-games and nothing else.

Comment: THanks@ Ross Burton, I replaced _append in my disro still its  30mb only. not adding any packages, like aboe modified Q?

Answer (score 0):

I think also that you schould place the inherit in the beginning :

```
inherit core-image
```

If you settled it after

```
IMAGE_FEATURES
```

then it will erase  your content settled before  and assign the core-image content

So a better image file is like

```
DESCRIPTION = "core-image-sato basic image "

LICENSE = "MIT"

inherit core-image

IMAGE_FEATURES += "splash package-management x11-base x11-sato ssh-server-dropbear hwcodecs"

IMAGE_INSTALL += "packagegroup-core-x11-sato-games"
```

BR.